# Extracting a string in between symbols

Tags: c++, string, file, pointers, text-extraction

I am actually trying to make use of this method Travels to extract information out
However I have problems doing it, I hope you guys will be able to help me out
I have problems trying to extract a string in between of " ", for eg "hello" to extract the hello. These are my methods below.

Travels Method

```
char *Travels(char Destination, char *originPtr)
{
do
{
    originPtr++;
}while (*originPtr != Destination);

originPtr++;
return originPtr;
}
```

In my main

```
int main()
{
//pointer for reading of file
char *startPtr1;
char Lines[256];

//read file and perform 
ifstream chordfile("myfile.txt");
if (chordfile.is_open())
{
    do
    {
        chordfile.getline(Lines, 256);
        startPtr1 = Lines;
        readFileInput(startPtr1);

    }while(chordfile.eof() == false);
    chordfile.close();
}

return 0;
}
```

In my readFileInput method (I will show the partial method)

```
//if it is insert.
if (strcmp(Stringg, "insert") == 0)
{
    char *SpecialPtr1;
    currentPtr1=Travels(' ',startPtr1);  // travels to Insert(*) 7 "your_data"
    int insertPeerNum = (int)atoi(currentPtr1); // travels to Insert (7) "your_data"
    currentPtr1=Travels(' ',currentPtr1); // travels to Insert 7(*)"your_data"
    currentPtr1=Travels('"',currentPtr1);
    SpecialPtr1=Travels('"',currentPtr1);
    *******this is the area which I am actually stucked at**********
    }
```

In the text file

```
Insert 7 "your_data"
Insert 7 "hello"
```

Comment: the * indicates the position of the pointer

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't specify the `homework` tag, I suggest you use `std::string`.  This data structure comes with many search and substring combinations.

For example to find text between double quotes:

```
#include <string>

//...

std::string::size_type    start_position = 0;
std::string::size_type    end_position = 0;
std::string               text = "My \"cat\" is black.\n";
std::string               found_text;

start_position = text.find("\"");
if (start_position != std::string::npos)
{
  ++start_position; // start after the double quotes.
  // look for end position;
  end_position = text.find("\"");
  if (end_position != std::string::npos)
  {
     found_text = text.substr(start_position, end_position - start_position);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your code:

1. In your Travels method, the condition  `while (*originPtr != Destination);` should be `while((*originPtr!=Destination) && (*originPtr != '\0'))`
2. Regarding retrieving the string, your logic appears a little skewed. You could have actually, tried to retrieve the string from in-between the two '"'. The code after the statement `currentPtr1=Travels('"',currentPtr1);`  can be

   char extractedstring[100] = {0};

   ```
   int i = 0;

   while(((*currentPtr1 != '"') && (*currentPtr1 != '\0')) && (i<100))
   {

      extractedstring[i] = *currentPtr1;

      currentPtr1++

      i++;
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

First, I recommend you to use std::string process methods, this will help a lot :)
Reference: [string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/)

```
// Helper Function 

inline bool find_first(size_t& pos, const std::string& st, const char flag='\"')
   {
       if(pos!= std::string::npos)
            pos=st.find_first_of(flag, pos);
       return (pos!= std::string::npos);
   }

inline bool find_last(size_t& pos, const std::string& st, const char flag='\"')
   {
      if(pos!= std::string::npos)
         pos=st.find_last_of(flag);
      return (pos!= std::string::npos);
   }
 template <class T>
   inline T from_string(const std::string& s)
   {
       T t;
       std::stringstream ss(s);
       ss >> t;
       return t;
   }



// Excerp Sample Code

std::string stdline = Lines.


size_t start
size_t end;
std::string text;
std::string numberText;
int number;


if (stdLine.compare("insert"))
{


if (find_first(start, stdLine,' ') && find_lats(end,stdLine,' ')
{

    numberText=stdLine.substr(start+1,end);
    number = from_string(numberText);
}

if (find_first(start, stdLine) && find_lats(end,stdLind)
{
    text=stdLine.substr(start+1,end); 

}

}
```